# How can i play a javascript sound without having the user to click a button?

Tags: javascript, audio, playback

I want to play a sound effect each time an event happens without having the user to click a button.

For example:

```
if (blabla > other_blabla){
     var hello = new Audio("this_that.wav");
     hello.play();
}
```

Comment: Which events are you trying to catch?

Comment: Im trying to catch a change between two integers and play a sound if the integer1 is bigger than integer2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a change event listener for all elements which you are trying to check

```js
// add change event listener for all elements thath match class "int"
document.querySelectorAll('.int').forEach(int => {
  int.addEventListener('change', event => {
    var int1 = document.getElementById('int1').value;
    var int2 = document.getElementById('int2').value;
    // check if int1 is bigger than int2
    if (int1 > int2) {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "play audio";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "do not play audio";
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<label>Integer 1: </label>
<input class="int" type="number" id="int1" value="1">
<label>Integer 2: </label>
<input class="int" type="number" id="int2" value="2">

<p id="result"></p>
```

try to change integer 1 to a number bigger than integer 2

Comment: Well thanks, but my question was how do i play an audio, because i do not seem to get the audio command of javascript

Comment: Does this help? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_audio_play.asp